# React Native: Pass target Location onPress to google maps or ios maps and execute a GPS Navigation towards said target

Tags: ios, google-maps, gps, react-native

I am looking for a way in order to enable a simple functionality for the app user.
The intended use-case would be - the user taps on the contact button in my app - sees our contact details and then presses on a "Navigate to" button which executes his navigation application and starts a GPS Navigation towards the target that got transferred on the button touch.

So far I have only found a custom map implementation into react native apps to display some location with maps - but no solution to open the navigation app and navigate towards a target.

Is it even possible ? (A simple link would be enough as reply - I might have missed something fundamental here :) )
Thank you for your help

Comment: re opened the question with correct termini http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501084/react-native-linking-to-another-app

Answer (score 1):

in the view you can add as below

```
<TouchableHighlight ref="statusbutton" onPress={this.showPopover.bind(this,this)}>
                    <View style={styles.mainStatus}></View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

And in the method

```
showPopover(self,event) {
    self.refs.statusbutton1.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
        //you can use the px and py values here.
    });
}
```