# React native Linking to another app

Tags: ios, react-native, applinks

I am trying to link to another app from my react native application (google maps for example).

I required the Linking module as it's written here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

My code contains a simple button which should open the navigation app and pass some location as properties:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
   onPress={ () =>{
     Linking.openURL("http://maps.google.com/maps=daddr=Wien")
     .catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err)); }}
>
   <Text>Navigate</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Upon loading the view I get no errors which implicates that requiring the module worked fine.

Upon taping the button I get the following error message :

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Linking.openURL')
```

---

I have followed these steps : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html and installed `npm install link --save` <- Maybe the issue is that this is the wrong module?? If it is the wrong one does anyone know how the correct one is called?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/819

Comment: First, have you done [these steps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) ?

Then, check if the URL can be opened with the `canOpenURL` method.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I have followed these steps :) - and installed : npm install link --save - yet the error still occurs

Comment: When I try to use canOpenURL I get the exact same Error except for the last part where .openURL changes to .canOpenURL :)

Comment: Can you post a rnplay fiddle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to `npm install link --save` or to use the "[Linking Libraries in iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html)" guide. The "`<Linking />` component" and the "Linking librairies action" are two very different things.

**`<Linking />`** is a component that allows you to open links (web urls, or links to other apps) and to detect when your app is called from a link (from a browser or another app, or a push notification for example). It is a core component of React Native and comes with the react-native npm package.

**Linking librairies** is necessary when you install a third party library (like [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) for example) and you need to add the dependencies to your iOS Xcode and Android Gradle build configurations. It is usually done with the `react-native link <package>` command, after you `npm install` it.

The only thing you **must** do is require or import `<Linking />` in your javascript file before using it. You do not even need the whole part about **Handling deep links** from the documentation. That is only for incoming links that open your app. All you need starts at [Opening external links](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#opening-external-links)

Now, why your code fails is a mystery. Here is a link to a working app that has the exact same behavior. A concise example would be:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Linking, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function Button() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://maps.google.com?q=stack+overflow+offices')}>
      <Text>Press me</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

You can also test it here on [rnplay](https://rnplay.org/apps/nATZwg).

I suggest cleaning your project, removing the node_modules folder and doing `npm install` again, and compiling your project new.

Comment: To actually start a navigation, use `http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=<lat>,<long>` for iOS and `http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=<lat>,<long>` for Android.

Comment: That's weird, two different urls?

Comment: They also point at two diffent maps. If you want google map the link should be the same...